# Why does pass-in-by-reference cause binding reference type error

Tags: c++

When use `for-loop`, I usually use reference like `for(auto& s : words)` to avoid temporary copy of each `word[i]`. But sometime it throws out error.

Could someone please help to clarify when it is ok to use `for(auto& s : words)` , and when we can ONLY use `for(auto s : words)` without reference? Any general rule or insight is very much appreciated!

Below is a specific example for illustration. In the main function, we have

```
    vector<string> topKFrequent(vector<string>& words, int k) {
        vector<string> res;
        if (words.empty()) return res;

        unordered_map<string, int> freq; 
        int max_freq = 0;
        for (auto& word : words) {
            freq[word]++;
            max_freq = max(max_freq, freq[word]);
        }

        // vector<Trie> bucket(max_freq + 1); //Question: if use struct on stack, then how to check whether bucket[i] contains valid words?
        vector<Trie*> bucket(max_freq + 1, NULL); //NOTE: optimization by using max_freq instead of words.size()

        for (auto& kv : freq) {

            Trie*& p_trie = bucket[kv.second]; //NOTE: must use reference &
            if (p_trie == NULL) {
                p_trie = new Trie(); //NOTE: call new Trie(), NOT TrieNode()!!!
            }
            p_trie->addWords(kv.first);
        }
}
```

In the self-defined `class Trie`, we have member function

```
void addWords(string& word) {

   //...omitted
}
```

`addWords(string& word)` will throw below error

```
error: binding reference of type 'std::__cxx11::string&' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&'} to 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>' discards qualifiers p_trie->addWords(kv.first); ~~~^~~~~,
```

Why does it say binding `string&` to `const string`?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] as required here please.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**

> Why does it say binding string& to const string?

Because you (attempt to) do so in the function call to addWords()

**Explanation**

`std::map::value_type` is defined as `std::pair<const key_type,mapped_type>`

Note the const key_type.

Hence, in your code `kv.first` is const, and you're trying to pass by reference into a non-const function.

You need to do either of the following:

1. Pass an `std::string const&`

```
 void addWords(string const& word) {
     //...omitted
 }
```

2. Pass by value (if addWords() needs to modify the local copy)

```
 void addWords(string word) {
     //...omitted
 }
```

Sources:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

Comment: Thanks. `unordered_map` also has `const key_type`, right?

Comment: @coder Correct. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/